# Reduce impact of outliners for frequency analysis by increasing signal length?

Tags: fft, fourier-transform, frequency, eeg

I am working on a project to detect drivers drowsiness with EEG signals. I am using the frequency values retrieved by FFT. I have some outliners (artifacts) in my signals, which I don't want to remove manually. I am doing some things automatically, but I can't catch every single outliner.

Right now I am analyzing a 1 sec (64 values) window and see that outliners have a big impact on the results. I'm wondering if increasing the window length could minimize the impact of the outliners?

If my assumption is right:

- Is there any source I can cite?
- Is this depending on the implementation?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'd say it depends on the character of your outliers. If on average there is one outlier in 64 samples, why do you think increasing the analysis window length would help?

Comment: @MaximilianMatthé I just wondered how much the outliners impact the frequency result. I can't say there is 1 outliner in average, otherwise you're right, it wouldn't change much. My hope is to attenuate the outliners by increasing the window length.